# Combination of Word and Notepad characters in passwords to Secret Agent

Tags: passwords

I have been trying to help a UK bank with its [Secret Agent encryption program](http://www.infoseccorp.com/products/secretagent/contents.htm).    I keep telling them they have problems with passwords as they use a variety of Notepad and Word, and if different programs are used to type and later replicate the password then they do not match, and it comes up as an invalid password. Frankly I tear my hair when they say "no that is not it".

Has anyone come across the conflict between using Word/Notepad with Secret Agent before? Could using a combination of Word and Notepad characters increase the level of encryption?

Comment: Can you try to improve your question instead of "Password Format"? Currently is not even a question.

Comment: I think you'll get a better response to this if you're a bit clearer about what's being done here.  I presume we're talking file transfer here and perhaps they're rotating passwords and storing the list in wordpad/notepad? I kind of hope I'm wrong 'cause that's a terrible idea :)

Comment: As Rory suggests, please explain what is going on here. It looks from a quick read that you are breaking all good practice recommendations, and I hope this isn't at one of the banks I worked at!

Comment: I had not really thought this through, So I will explain in greater detail. They send encrypted data via a disc in the post. A password for the decryption programme is sent separately in a typed letter.

Comment: Sorry I did not finish. The recipient then has to look at the thirty characters forming the password [they say in word or note pad] and try and replicate it. Even when you type it out in word then ctrl c and ctrl V paste it into the Secret Agent window it does not work. It relies on what your eyes tell you, and we all see things differently compare ' to` in word quotes can auto correct and I wonder if this is part of the problem.

Comment: Did it again I keep on hitting the wrong key I am so annoyed. I think you have to use the programme the password was created in to correctly replicate it, yet the protocol says word or note pad even though I have told them the same key strokes have different binary text values in word and notepad. Interestingly in "pages" they are equivalent to "notepad" binary text, "word" is different.

Comment: If the program ("secret agent") doesn't work as expected, you certainly should consider contacting their customer / tech support?

Comment: With your update this sounds like it really is not a Security issue, but a problem with your application. As SEJPM says, you need to contact your tech support.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand the question right, your users are storing their passwords in text files (Notepad) and Word documents. This is an **extremely** unsafe practice.
Everybody who has read access to the place where these passwords are stored, can see the passwords. Moreover, the passwords will be visible if users copy-paste them.

Your users should be storing their passwords in a Password Manager.

> Could using a combination of Word and Notepad Characters" increase the level of encryption?

Using exotic symbols in a password make it harder to brute-force an encryption. But as you've seen, the way you are doing it now, also makes things inconvenient for your users. And if things become too inconvenient, users will start finding ways around it - and probably compromise the security protocols while doing so.

Several password managers come with the option to generate passwords, and let you select which symbols are/aren't allowed in the password.
In this way you can have passwords that include exotic symbols, that will yet be usable on all devices.

Comment: I think "extremely" should be made bigger.

Comment: Slight terminology clarification for the sentence after the quote:  Using exotic symbols in a *password* may make it harder to brute force.  An encryption key (for modern digital encryption schemes) consists of bits, not characters, and should be properly random.  Characters, exotic or otherwise shouldn't be introduced into the conversation.

Comment: @Xander Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, **you should be using a password manager!** Do not use word and notepad.

However I'd like to address some mis-conceptions in your question as well.

> Has anyone come across the conflict between using Word/NotePad with Secret Agent before? Could using a combination of Word and Notepad Characters" increase the level of encryption?

'Word' and 'Notepad' characters is probably a misnomer. Characters are generally universal (Unicode / UTF-8), regardless of which program you use to store them.

With NotePad, it may be that the characters are not stored under the currently selected Character Set. (File->Save As) (i.e. using older Windows or Latin-1 encoding)

With Word, it may be that certain characters are replaced. For example regular double-quotes " may become angled double-quotes “”

There is a strong possibility that the programme you are using does not support the character you have chosen, and it is silently broken when you first set up their account. This is the case for older (and newer) authentication systems that do not support all manner of Unicode / UTF-8 characters.

> Has anyone come across the conflict between using Word/NotePad with Secret Agent before?

I would suggest you speak with the [creators/owners of SecretAgent](http://www.infoseccorp.com/products/secretagent/contents.htm) to find out their support for exotic characters. If it is not supported, you should not be using them because it could introduce problems accessing files, especially when switching OS/platform, or upgrading to a newer version of their program.

> Could using a combination of ... characters increase the level of encryption?

Not necessarily. Length will do far more for your encrypted files than special characters.

What you should be considering is how likely it is for a super-computer to guess the password. There are situations where they can do this offline and try millions of passwords per second, so that is why you want a sufficiently long (and somewhat complex) password.

Using unusual characters might help with this, especially if the hackers do not yet know you are using this technique.

However, the best solution is to **make passwords of 12 characters or more, which are *completely random*** (i.e. use a password generator), using all manner of **plain keyboard characters**. If your passwords are long enough, then there is no need for exotic characters.